# Dialogflow webhook - First fulfill the current Intent and then trigger another Intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

Lets say I have two Intents `QuotationIntent` and `SalesRepresentativeIntent`.
The `QuotationIntent`, gets some input from the user and returns appropriate result through web-hook. After successful fulfillment, I want to trigger the `SalesRepresentativeIntent` to check with the user if they want our sales representative to call them. I am able to trigger the Intent through [events](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#invoking_event_from_webhook). But the problem is `QuotationIntent` fulfillment message is skipped.

[image]

I don't want to add a follow up intent directly to `QuotationIntent`, as there are many intents from which I will have to trigger `SalesRepresentativeIntent`.

Can you please tell me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use context here. Add output context say "`QuotationDone`" in your `QuotationIntent`. Use the same context as the input context for `SalesRepresentativeIntent`. This way `SalesRepresentativeIntent` will be triggered only when `QuotationIntent` is completed.

To trigger `SalesRepresentativeIntent` you need to add either "user says" phrases and train your agent or add [EVENTS](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events) to your intent.

This way your `SalesRepresentativeIntent` will only be triggered when the following condition met:

```
if((inputContext is present) AND (event is triggered OR user says phrase is present)){
      trigger `SalesRepresentativeIntent`
} else {
      fallback intent called
}
```

The other way you can do your task is to use [SLOTS](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters). Here in single intent, you can have multiple parameters collected. Add parameters that you want to collect. In your case whatever you are collecting in `QuotationIntent` you can collect it in first few parameters and make them as required and then the things you need to collect in `SalesRepresentativeIntent` you can collect in other parameters in the same intent. Arrange the order of the parameters in the order you want your bot asks from your users. This way your responses will be asked automatically depending on the parameters are collected from the user or not.

Comment: HI Abhinav, thanks for the answer. I did as you said, now the `QuotationIntent` fulfillment is happening, but the `SalesRepresentativeIntent` is not automatically triggered.

Comment: make sure SalesRepresentativeIntent has input context same as output context of QuotationIntent. Also, the lifespan for output context should be a number which is greater than the total interaction with QuotationIntent. you can try putting as 5. Which will keep the output context alive for 5 consecutive interactions. Please check following link https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts. The SalesRepresentativeIntent will only be triggered if((outputContextofQuotationIntent == inputContextofSalesRepIntent) && (salesRepIntentUserSays phrase are used || salesRepIntent event is called))

Comment: I need a way to trigger the `SalesRepresentativeIntent` directly.(Without the user typing any phrases)

Comment: @AnandMurali I have updated my answer. You need either user says phrases or an event.

Comment: you may require one intent with multiple parameters/slots